# Code getting build locally but Getting build erroron TF in build definition

Tags: c#, devops, build-error, azure-pipelines, assembly-references

I wrote a project that uses entity framework and is working fine locally. But when i try to run an automated build using VSTS I get am error while running build definition. I know it is getting caused by Entity framework reference but I am not able to get the root cause. Here is the build error for reference.

```
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z ##[error]MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\MovieContext.cs(4,19): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z MovieContext.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\Movies.Repository.csproj]
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z ##[error]MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\MovieContext.cs(5,19): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z MovieContext.cs(5,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\Movies.Repository.csproj]
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z ##[error]MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\MovieContext.cs(7,29): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z MovieContext.cs(7,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\Movies.Repository.csproj]
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z ##[error]MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\MovieContext.cs(17,33): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateDatabaseIfNotExists' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z MovieContext.cs(17,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateDatabaseIfNotExists' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\Movies.Repository.csproj]
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z ##[error]MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\MovieContext.cs(40,35): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z MovieContext.cs(40,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\Movies.Repository.csproj]
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z ##[error]MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\MovieRepository.cs(3,19): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z MovieRepository.cs(3,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\a\1\s\MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\Movies.Repository.csproj]
2016-12-08T07:42:52.1197143Z ##[error]MyMovieDatabase\Movies.Repository\MovieContext.cs(14,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Can you post the lines from your Movies.Repositroy.csproj which refer the entity framework dlls

Comment: @SethuBala `  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

Comment: Hi, can you share the build steps that you have in VSTS for the particular build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your Reference in .csproject which uses local reference(it takes from packages folder in your hard disk). Obviously This won't work when deployed in the server. Change that to the nugetpackages path. Change the Hint Path for all the references in the format I have given below

```
$(NugetPackagesPath)\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\Entity‌​Framework.dll
```

You can use the below piece of code which defines the NugetPackagesPath

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- EnlistmentRoot is the base directory where all of the module root directories reside. --> 
    <EnlistmentRoot>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</EnlistmentRoot>
    <EnlistmentRoot Condition="'$(EnlistmentRoot)' != ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(EnlistmentRoot)'))</EnlistmentRoot>
    <EnlistmentRoot Condition="'$(EnlistmentRoot)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(EnlistmentRoot)')">$(EnlistmentRoot)\</EnlistmentRoot>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- NuGetPackagesPath is the base directory for all nuget packages. --> 
    <NuGetPackagesPath>$(EnlistmentRoot)Ref\Packages</NuGetPackagesPath>
    <NuGetPackagesPath Condition="'$(NuGetPackagesPath)' != ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(NuGetPackagesPath)'))</NuGetPackagesPath>
    <NuGetPackagesPath Condition="'$(NuGetPackagesPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(NuGetPackagesPath)')">$(NuGetPackagesPath)\</NuGetPackagesPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks @SethuBala Thanku. I have a little idea about structure of .csproj file. How $(NugetPackagesPath) will be retrieved ? Do I need to define $(NugetPackagesPath) somewhere ?

Comment: @MadhurMaurya I have edited my answer for your above query