# Where/how is $(NuGetPackagesPath) set?

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a lot of entries in my app.config like so:

$(NuGetPackagesPath)\System.Net.Http.4.3.3\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll

Where/how is $(NuGetPackagesPath) set?  It kind of looks like an environment variable.

I typed set at a command prompt and it's nowhere to find there.

Comment: [I don't believe NuGet ever sets NuGetPackagesPath](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/search?q=NuGetPackagesPath&unscoped_q=NuGetPackagesPath). I think someone before you has manually edited the file in that way.  I also don't know why anything in your app.config would point to assemblies in the packages folder. Binding redirects normally have paths to files in the bin folder.

Comment: If I search for NuGetPackagesPath in stack overflow and on the web generally.  I see it mentioned a fair bit, but I can't find anything on how/where it is set.

Comment: It looks like the answer to  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034411/code-getting-build-locally-but-getting-build-erroron-tf-in-build-definition/41035717#41035717) also answers my question.